# Is there any way to make games smoother on Macbook Pro 13'?

Tags: macbook-pro, games

I currently have Macbook pro 13' and I am trying to games like Samurai vs Zombie and Contract Killer 2. Both of these are not highend games with not so detailed textures. Yet they get stuck after every click.

Is there some way to do away with this ?

Comment: Please be more specific on your version of Macbook Pro you have: processor, video card, RAM, and Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

Turn down all detail in the game (turn it up incrementally later).

Close all running apps, except for the game(s). This includes your email client, web browser, etc. Check your "Login Items" under System Preferences. Ensure you don't have any background tasks that are consuming CPU cycles and/or system memory.

If you have minimal system memory (RAM), it would be a good idea to upgrade since RAM is so affordable now. You can never have enough RAM. I would recommend at least 8GB.

Activity Monitor will also show the CPU load on your system when it's sitting idle. It will show apps that might be running unbeknownst to you.